# Replace all numbers except zero using sql query

Tags: apache-spark-sql

**Input data**

| Number |
| --- |
| 0 |
| 2 |
| 10 |
| 0 |
| 202 |
| 333 |

Replace all numbers except 0 as 'more than 0' using SQL query and find the count of 0 and more than 0

**Expected Output**

| Number | Count |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 2 |
| more than 0 | 4 |

Comment: You've tagged with MySQL, Oracle, and Apache Spark.  What is your actual database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure on your SQL database, but this logic is one way:

```
SELECT
Number,
COUNT (Number) Count
FROM 
(
SELECT
CASE
WHEN Number = 0 THEN '0' ELSE 'more than 0' END Number
FROM table
)
GROUP BY 1
```

Answer (score 0):

here is how you can do it :

```
select 
  case when Number = 0 then '0' else 'more than 0' end as Number
  , count(*) as Count
from table 
group by case when Number = 0 then '0' else 'more than 0' end
```

assuming numbers are always >= 0